# spring-boot: .properties settings does not write to log file but .yml does

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logback

I have a simple spring-boot app where I am testing logging to a file. Not using any log config except default, out-of-the-box spring-boot.

I had success writing default logs to a file ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DK8z6yO3BY)) where `application.yml` is in src/main/resources:

application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
  pattern:
    file: "%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
  file:
    name: /Users/myuser/Documents/java/spring/demo/src/main/resources/logs/demo-log.log
    clean-history-on-start: true
```

But I **cannot** duplicate those results if I replace the yml file with `src/main/resources/application.properties` (below). A file is created, but no content is written after `mvn clean install`, then `mvn spring-boot:run`:

application.properties

```
logging.level.root=Debug    
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
logging.file.name=/Users/myuser/Documents/java/spring/demo/src/main/resources/logs/newlogs.log
logging.file.clean-history-on-start=true
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.postcommons</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>spring boot project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Why is the log file not being populated with application.properties like it did with application.yml?

Comment: Is there a space before `logging.file.name`?

Comment: In the question there is, yes. But there was not in the code. i'll try to fix it above

Comment: If you use `logging.pattern.console=` have you got at least on console?

Comment: I get console output with both files without specifying logging.pattern.console.